# Check fitness of 3D model 1 into 3D model 2 c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to check if 3D model 1 fits into 3D model 2

you can see an example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu1cJ.gif

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also please post actual code, as text, properly formatted, not images of code